# Custom admin form works in localhost not works in server in magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

Custom admin form  show in localhost  not display in server in magento 2

I have follow this reference to create a custom form in admin https://www.maximehuran.fr/en/layouts-and-forms-on-magento-2-admin/

**In LocalHost:**

[image]

**In Server:**

[image]

Comment: Is there any log in the console?

Comment: there is no error in log file

Comment: In local & server both have same deployment mode ?
if yes then maybe you need to set production mode in local system and then check ur functionality.

Comment: I mean for browser console log.

Comment: There is no console error https://prnt.sc/r5hlj4

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Ui component form instead of blocks if you want to write less code and let magento make all work for you. If you want to control whole process u can try blocks as well.

**You can follow** [this](https://webkul.com/blog/create-ui-form-magento2-part-1/) **tutorial**